# Textarea border color not changing completely

Tags: html, css, border

I'm trying to make the border gray, and for some reason only 2 "edges" / half of the box of the
`<input type="text">` are gray while the `<textarea>` border is fine.

Any idea why is this happening? both have the same class `.fill-form-style`

```
.fill-form-font {        
    padding: 8px;
    border-radius: 20px;
    border-color: gray;
    outline: none;
    font-size: 16px;
}
```

And this is the HTML of the input and textarea:

```
<input type="text" name="nickname" maxlength="22" size="25" class="fill-form-font">
<textarea name="content" cols="65" rows="10" style="resize: none;" class="fill-form-font"> Text Here </textarea>
```

Comment: so u wanna make a sharp edge on any two corners?

Comment: It's working fine on my end when I dump it into a jsfiddle.  Perhaps you have some other css throughout your page that is affecting it...?

Do an "Inspect Element" to see what is going on with the css.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `border-style:solid;` This will stop the border from being the two different colours.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xmq06voc/)

Thanks to some messing around (and Paulie_D in comments [Thanks!]) I found out it's because of the `inset` border style.

You can also use shorthand `border` which then means you have less lines in your css.

```
border:1px solid #f00;
```

Here's a working snippet:

```css
.fill-form-font{        
    padding: 8px;
    border-radius: 20px;
    border-color: red;
    border-style:solid;
    outline: none;
    font-size: 16px;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" name="nickname" maxlength="22" size="25" class="fill-form-font" >
<textarea name="content" cols="65" rows="10" style="resize: none;" class="fill-form-font"> Text Here </textarea>
```

Comment: The default style is `inset' I think. check the Computed Styles

Comment: You can mark this as accepted to help people in the future, glad I could help! @user5119866

Answer (score 1):

That's because of `User Agent Style`. You need to use `border` to override the user agent border. Example:

```css
.fill-form-font {        
  padding: 8px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 16px;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" name="nickname" maxlength="22" size="25" class="fill-form-font">

<textarea name="content" cols="60" rows="10" style="resize: none;" class="fill-form-font"> Text Here </textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution...

```
.fill-form-font{        
    padding: 8px;
    border-radius: 20px;
    border: 1px solid gray;
    outline: none;
    font-size: 16px;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ew2orox0/ live example

Answer (score 0):

By default, browser users `border-style: inset;` and you should change it to use `border-style: solid`.
You could just add that property or use the `border` definition in just one line:
`border: 1px solid gray; /* I set 1px but chrome, by default, sets 2px */`